# How do I link text boxes in iBooks Author?

Tags: ibooks-author

I've been trying out iBooks author, and one thing i want to be able to do is to allow text overflow from one custom text box to another. In pages this is done either by clicking the blue little symbol in the lower-right part of a text box with too much text, and link it to another, or by going to the menu format->text box->add linked text box. In iBooks Author, however, this last option is greyed out for no apparent reason, and the blue link symbol never appears. Any suggestions?

Comment: Hmm. I have never use that before, But I got it to work on  one of the text boxes by resizing it and the blue handle appeared. But can not get it to do it on others?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the Botany sample, the text boxes seem to work as expected with the caveat that you have to intentionally click on one of the four corner handles of the text box to make the blue linking triangles appear.

I took a [small video](http://cl.ly/DfDR) showing the controls reacting to mouse events.

From there, linking works as expected from the perspective of Pages.

[image: flowing text boxes in iBooks Author]

Comment: I found out that (to me) it only works if I use the already existing text boxes, by resizing them and creating new through them. This works for me, so problem solved. I had originally created a new text box with the tool visible at the tool field, and then linking won't work, for some reason.

Answer (score 1):

This is very difficult to find. When you create the text box after Enable: Editable on pages using this layout you should use the tag body, when a text box has the tag body will show the connection lines.

Comment: This is the answer that solved this for me. As an additional note, iBA will alert you if you have another frame tagged with "body" already on the page somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

I have found that it is necesary to give some special properties to the text boxes inside of layout column, for example:

1. Select the view menu on the top bar
2. Select Show layouts
3. Select a textbox
4. Open layout inspector
5. **Enable**: Editable on pages using this layout

Then in format menu: Format > Text box > Show connection lines

The arrows and blue lines appear when toggling the menu item **Show connection lines**

When use the same layout to create a page or section, the textbox must contain tne blue arrows and connection lines to.

I found that this solution is not applicable to all the textboxes, it seems to deppend on the text style or something.

Comment: I cannot find the fifth step in the layout inspector. All I can choose is column width and number of columns?

Comment: This one gave me what I needed.  I didn't even know where the layout editor was previously.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

To summarise:

1. You have to be in layout mode. So select View menu on the top bar, and ensure that Show layouts is enabled.
2. use the Text Box icon on the top menu bar to create a text box
3. Select the text box and open the inspector, go to the Layout inspector and enable "Editable on pages using this layout" and ensure that the Tag is set to "body"
4. the link handles should now be visible. Click on them to create additional linked text boxes.

Note: you can only use one body tag per layout